# Python while loop returning 0 for variable

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

While using this code:

```
total_cost = int(input("How much does your dream house cost?"))
annual_salary = int(input("What is your annual salary?"))
portion_saved = float(input("What portion of your annual salary would you like to save?(As a decimal)"))
portion_down_payment = 0.25
current_savings = 0
r = 0.04
monthly_salary = (annual_salary / 12)  #portion saved will be monthly so this is easier
monthly_savings = (monthly_salary * portion_saved) #a percentage will be the same monthly or yearly
num_of_months = 0

while current_savings < (total_cost * portion_down_payment):
    current_savings += monthly_savings
    num_of_months += 1
    current_savings = (current_savings * r) 

print(num_of_months)
```

Python prints 0 after I input all the required inputs.
Did I set up my while loop incorrectly?

Comment: Did you step through the code line-by-line in a debugger to see what's happening in the loop?

Comment: Can you give an example of the inputs that you add to get 0? With inputs `100000`, `50000`, and `0.5` my interpreter does not print 0. It enters a probaly infinite loop (I assume it to be infinite because I added some print statements and cannot predict it ever leaving the while loop).

Comment: Try `current_savings += (current_savings * r)`

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.

Comment: You failed to do the basic debugging we expect.  See this [lovely debugging site](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help.  If nothing else, trace your values with a strategic `print` or two -- the error in computation is immediately obvious.

Answer (score 0):

```
while current_savings < (total_cost * portion_down_payment):
    current_savings += monthly_savings
    num_of_months += 1
    current_savings = (current_savings * r)
```

If you look at the 3rd line of your loop, you'll find you set current_savings  to 0.04 times the previous one (which was equal to the monthly_savings in first iteration),
So infact the values for current saving change for every iteration are so small:

```
How much does your dream house cost?10000
What is your annual salary?100
What portion of your annual salary would you like to save?(As a decimal)1
0
0.33333333333333337
0.34666666666666673
0.34720000000000006
0.3472213333333334
0.3472221866666667
0.34722222080000004
0.3472222221653334
0.3472222222199467
0.3472222222221312
0.3472222222222186
0.3472222222222221
0.3472222222222222
0.3472222222222222
0.3472222222222222
0.3472222222222222
0.3472222222222222
```

that the code goes in an infinite loop.

and I don't really suppose you plan to do that?